# WCF & REST & SOAP

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure

I have some ASMX web services that take in a string parameter and return a json string. They look like this:

```
WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
     [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
     public string MyWebMethod1(string TheParameter1)
     {
           TheClassThatDoesTheWork MyClass = new  TheClassThatDoesTheWork();
           return MyClass.DoTheWork1(TheParameter);
     }

     [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
     public string MyWebMethod2(string TheParameter2)
     {
           TheClassThatDoesTheWork MyClass = new  TheClassThatDoesTheWork();
           return MyClass.DoTheWork2(TheParameter);
     }
}
```

For the moment, they work on IIS in HTTP. I want to move the app in Azure, and use WCF for the web services and make them work in HTTPS.
What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way for a WCF service to return a JSON is to use webhttpbinding, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx

To secure it run it over HTTPS/SSL.

Comment: Do I have acces to HTTPContext.Current.Session in WCF?

Comment: You would use the builtin WCF per session functionality for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

Comment: Ok, can the user be logged-in the app on IIS (or Azure) and somehow have the session also be accessible in WCF? User in my app will log in using forms authentification and will then be making ajax calls to the WCF service.

Comment: You need to enable ASP.NET compatibility in your WCF service. You'll need both the related service attribute and the config setting. More details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx